# wifi dongle, iwpriv ra0 ATE command not working

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

Trying to execute ATE commands on ralink rt3070 wifi dongle,

```
# iwpriv ra0 set ATE=ATESTART

Interface doesn't accept private ioctl...
set (8BE2): Invalid argument
```

Anyone got any idea?

It is suppose to work, according to [this](http://rt2870linux.googlecode.com/hg/sta_ate_iwpriv_usage.txt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it,
in sta_ate_iwpriv_usage.txt it says,

```
To turn on ATE functionality, you have to add compile flag "RALINK_ATE" to Makefile
```

it can be enabled in RT3070_LinuxSTA_V2.3.0.1_20100208/os/linux/config.mk

```
# Support ATE function
HAS_ATE=y
```

disable the rt3070sta module, make and make install again, insert module,
it should run ATE commands without any problem.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

It's supposed to work under the condition that you install their [old hacked drivers.](https://code.google.com/p/rt2870linux/)

Also note that on up-to-date kernels, the WEXT interface (used by iwpriv/iwlist/iwconfig) is getting more and more deprecated, replaced by the netlink nl80211 interface, as used by 'iw'.

Comment: i've been using 
RT3070_LinuxSTA_V2.3.0.1_20100208 which gives rt3070sta kernel module, 
the system is 2.6.38.8-32.fc15.i686.PAE

gonna test code.google driver that you mentioned.